# Как показать объект в иерархии, в скрипте которого возникло исключение?

Tags: c#, unity3d, исключения

Решил использовать try catch , если возникает исключение NullReferenceException.

мой код :

```
            using System.Collections;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using UnityEngine;
            using UnityEngine.UI;
            using System;
    public static class Utility {
        public static void SetActive(this MonoBehaviour obj, bool active) {
            obj.enabled = active;
        }
    }
            public class FreeCamera : MonoBehaviour
                {
                public GameObject Drone = null;
                public Camera camera = null;
                public Camera cameraDrone = null;
                public bool ScriptBool = true;
                public Dropdown dropdown;

        public void ActiveScript(bool valueBool) //valueBool = false
        {
            GetComponent<RTSCameraController>()              ?.SetActive(true);
            GetComponent<MouseLook>()                        ?.SetActive(false);
            GetComponent<ScenarioCamera>()                   ?.SetActive(!valueBool);
            GetComponent<CameraSwitchBetweenGameObjManager>()?.SetActive(!valueBool);
            GetComponent<CameraRotateAroundManager>()        ?.SetActive(valueBool);
            GetComponent<RTCCamera>()                        ?.SetActive(valueBool);

            cameraDrone.enabled = valueBool;
            camera.enabled = !valueBool;

            Drone.gameObject.SetActive(valueBool);
            if(Drone.gameObject.activeSelf) {
                if(camera && Drone) {
                    Drone.transform.position = camera.transform.position;
                }
            }
        }
                public void checkNullReferenceException(NullReferenceException e, bool valueBool) {
                    if(e.Source== "Drone") {
                        GameObject Drone = GameObject.Find("Drone");
                        if(Drone) {
                            Drone.gameObject.SetActive(valueBool);
                        }
                    } else if(e.Source== "Camera") {
                        foreach (Camera c in Camera.allCameras) {
                        if(c.name=="Camera") {
                            cameraDrone = c;
                            break;
                        } 
                        }
                        if(camera) {
                            camera.enabled=!valueBool;
                        } else {
                            camera = Camera.main;
                            if(camera) {
                                camera.enabled=!valueBool;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(e.Source== "cameraDrone") {
                        foreach (Camera c in Camera.allCameras) {
                            if(c.name=="DroneCamera") {
                                cameraDrone = c;
                                break;
                            } 
                        }
                        if(cameraDrone) {
                            cameraDrone.enabled = valueBool;
                        }
                    }
                }
         public void SwitchingScript() {
            if(ScriptBool) {
                try {
                    ActiveScript(true);
                    ScriptBool=false;
                } catch (NullReferenceException e) {
                    Debug.Log("e.Source="+e.Source);
                    checkNullReferenceException(e,false);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Debug.Log("e.Source="+e.Source);
                    Debug.Log("e.Message="+e.Message);
                    Debug.Log("e.StackTrace="+e.StackTrace);
                    Debug.Log("e.TargetSite="+e.TargetSite);
                    Debug.Log("e.InnerException="+e.InnerException);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    ActiveScript(false);
                    ScriptBool=true;
                } catch (NullReferenceException e) {
                    Debug.Log("e.Source="+e.Source);
                    checkNullReferenceException(e,true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Debug.Log("e.Source="+e.Source);
                    Debug.Log("e.Message="+e.Message);
                    Debug.Log("e.StackTrace="+e.StackTrace);
                    Debug.Log("e.TargetSite="+e.TargetSite);
                    Debug.Log("e.InnerException="+e.InnerException);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Как получить "e.Source="+e.Source и название исключения чтоб его обработать?
То что сейчас выводит выглядит так :

```
e.Source=
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FreeCamera:dropdown_IndexChange(Int32) (at Assets/LevelChanger/Menu/Player/FreeCamera.cs:128)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()


e.Message=The variable Drone of FreeCamera has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the Drone variable of the FreeCamera script in the inspector.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FreeCamera:dropdown_IndexChange(Int32) (at Assets/LevelChanger/Menu/Player/FreeCamera.cs:129)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()


e.StackTrace=  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.GameObject.SetActive(UnityEngine.GameObject,bool)
  at FreeCamera.ActiveScript (System.Boolean valueBool) [0x00096] in D:\Unity\satelite_1.0.0.git\satelite\Assets\LevelChanger\Menu\Player\FreeCamera.cs:31 
  at FreeCamera.dropdown_IndexChange (System.Int32 index) [0x0000e] in D:\Unity\satelite_1.0.0.git\satelite\Assets\LevelChanger\Menu\Player\FreeCamera.cs:122 
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FreeCamera:dropdown_IndexChange(Int32) (at Assets/LevelChanger/Menu/Player/FreeCamera.cs:130)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()


e.TargetSite=
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FreeCamera:dropdown_IndexChange(Int32) (at Assets/LevelChanger/Menu/Player/FreeCamera.cs:131)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()



e.InnerException=
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
FreeCamera:dropdown_IndexChange(Int32) (at Assets/LevelChanger/Menu/Player/FreeCamera.cs:132)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem:Update()
```

Comment: Выводится сообщение с `"e.Source="`? А в `checkNullReferenceException` нет ли этой же ошибки?

Comment: @gil9red Нет не выводиться "e.Source="

Comment: @gil9red checkNullReferenceException  не занет такого исключения

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, почему вы написали `Но мой код ловит исключения :`, если try/catch только в одном месте и судя по отсутствию `e.Source=` исключение не ловится. Ок, наверное, вы опечатались. В любом случае, когда исключение валит приложение должна дана трасса стека где будут функции и место возникновения исключения

Comment: @gil9red  я перепутал мой код не ловит исключения

Comment: Раз не ловит, значит падает не `NullReference`. Поставьте еще один `catch` с `Exception` и выведите тип пойманного исключения.

Comment: Создал банальную конструкцию с обращением к `[SerializeField]` объекта и try-catch - всё сработало. Вы уверены, что ваша ошибка падает именно внутри обрабатываемых границ?

Comment: @M. Green Сейчас переделаю вопрос . Падает если нет  catch (Exception e) {} . Мне надо получить имя переменой  и название исключения чтоб обработать исключение

Comment: @M. Green "e.Source="+e.Source пустой если не назначен объект

Comment: @M. Green Как мне получить имя переменой в которой возникло исключение ?

Comment: Никак не получить, исключения так не работают, что и не подразумевалось. Пытаться получить какую-то информацию для логики через исключения - странно. Выводите в сообщении исключения номер строки, зачем вам именно переменная?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Имя переменой нужно чтоб в сцене попробовать найти этот объект и если нет его , то тогда сообщать о проблеме

Comment: Как связаны название переменной и название GameObject?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker GameObject называется так же как и переменная

Comment: Почему бы тогда просто не записать в сообщение исключения `this.name`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101509/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-riotbr3aker).

Comment: Максимум что можно вытащить - номер строки, номер последней успешной пройденой строки для рилиза, смещение в IL-коде, по которому вручную можно найти и номер линии кода, и переменную. Програмно её найти - проблематично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вся эта идея с "как найти имя переменной" - пустая трата времени. Если стоит задача найти, какой GameObject кинул исключение, проще воспользоваться полезными методами редактора.

```
try {
    // code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.LogError($"Caught exception {e.GetType()}: {e.Message}");
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    EditorGUIUtility.PingObject(this.gameObject);
    #endif
}
```

`EditorGUIUtility.PingObject` выделит объект в иерархии и вам не придется искать его вручную. Также данный код сделает лог с типом и сообщением исключения. В принципе, ровно то, чего вы и хотели.

---

EDIT - Спасибо @M.Green

Можно передавать объект для пинга прямо в перегрузку `Debug.Log`:

```
try {
    // code
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Debug.LogError($"Caught exception {e.GetType()}: {e.Message}", this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Caught exception UnityEngine.UnassignedReferenceException: The variable Drone of FreeCamera has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the Drone variable of the FreeCamera script in the inspector.

Comment: this ...на верно что то другое надо пердавать

Comment: @IvanTriumphov да, прошу прощения, исправил.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov ну а в логе у вас ровно та информация, которую вы искали, разве нет? :)

Comment: я так понял вы клоните к тому ,что моя функция checkNullReferenceException . Которая ищет объект , если возникла исключение .Не нужна .

Comment: Caught exception UnityEngine.UnassignedReferenceException: The variable Drone of FreeCamera has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the Drone variable of the FreeCamera script in the inspector.

Comment: даже если добавить this.gameObject

Comment: Вся задумка которая была искать на сцене , если возникло исключение

Comment: Вы всмотритесь в поведение редактора, метод `EditorGUIUtility.PingObject` "выделит" объект, скрипт которого кинул исключение. Вам не нужно ничего искать, оно уже вам покажет этот объект. Сообщение, которые вы мне приводите - это ровно то, что было в выкинутом исключении, это не "ошибка", а сообщение, которое я вывожу через `Debug.LogError`.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, поправьте, если ошибаюсь. Если при вызове методов Debug.Log... вторым параметром передавать объект для подсветки мы, кажется, получаем то же самое поведение.

Comment: @M.Green да, перегрузка с контекстом именно так и работает, но я не смотрел исходный код `Debug.Log`, внутри перегрузка выкидывает пинг при билде или же вся перегрузка вообще из билда выпиливается?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, вообще вызов метода Debug.Log выпиливается, как я понимаю

Comment: @M.Green, нет, дебаг логи не выпиливаются, что кажется странным решением, пока не натыкаешься на `Application.logMessageReceived`. Поэтому даже релизный билд будет тратить время на логи. Чтобы полностью от них избавиться, лучше написать свои врапперы с `Conditional` :)